# bootstrap - child fill 100% of parent, but not larger

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

```css
html,body, .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.page-header {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

#icons {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div id='header' class='page-header col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12'>
      <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3'><img id='logo' src='img/logo.png' class='img-responsive'></div>
      <div id='icons' class='col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-2'>icons</div>
    </div>
    <div id='navigation' class='col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12' style='border:1px solid black;height:100%;'>navigation</div>
  </div>

  <div class='row row-eq-height'>
    <div id='left' class='col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 col-md-2' style='border:1px solid green;'>left</div>
    <div id='right' class='col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-md-10' style='border:1px solid green;'>right<br></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

OKAY maybe I wasn't so clear what I actually want, so I try it again with another picture:

[image]

I want the sidebar and content divs to fill the whole rest of the parent div, without a scrollbar, so that it is not getting bigger than the actual parent div. If I use height:100% on the child, it is getting to large, because it takes the (navigation + header) + 100%. So I tried several things. I tried it with flexboxes with boostrap4, it didn't work, as I wanted. I could say height:calc(100%- x). But the problem is that x is not a fixed value, since it is responsive.

So what can I do, to fill the rest of the parent(100%) with the child to have a min-height of 100% without enlarging the page?

Comment: Generally speaking it's a bad idea to apply styling to the elements of your grid or layout system. Doing so is essentially "hacking the core", which makes development and maintenance more difficult. Use the grid to lay out your content, and use content containers, inside the grid, to apply additional layout styling.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height of `.row-eq-height` to auto.

I mean like this:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: auto;
}
```

In case you want, you could also provide a min-height like `min-height:100px;`

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/digitalrevenge/p7q0ohrf/

Comment: thanks but this doesn't really solve the problem, since left and right still don't end at the bottom of the page, just only of a px-height I want to.

Comment: @André Yeah, but the height will adjust itself automatically based on what you put inside the container. Can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: it is nice that it adjust itself. But I would need it to have a min-height:100% so when I give it another background color it covers the whole rest of the page. That's why I need at a min-height for "left" and "right" :)... do you have a solution?

Comment: @André Nope I don't :(

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, You are fixing the height of you container. That is causing the problem. Remove height from container and your content area will grow automatically because that is in flex. You can also remove height from `.row-eq-height` class and navigation also. rest is OK.

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem, I edited my actual question.